# How to print words in a range in Python?

Tags: python

Suppose I have the below string:

> `"Python is a programming language that lets you work more quickly and integrate your systems more effectively. You can learn to use Python and see almost immediate gains in productivity and lower maintenance costs."`

Start word position: 5
End word position: 10

Any suggestions for printing all the words from position from 5 to 10?

Comment: Choose an answer if it worked for you...

Comment: It said I have to wait 10 minutes for choosing. I am waiting.

Answer (score 3):

Like this, assuming `words` is the string:

```
print words.split()[4:10]
```

Comment: @ATOzTOA :( there, fixed _that_.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you need entire words (not characters) from position 5 to 10 both inclusive, you can do the following:

```
print sentence.split(" ")[4:10]
```

For example:

```
>>> print "Python is a programming language that lets you work more quickly \
       and integrate your systems more effectively. You can learn to use \
       Python and see almost immediate gains in productivity and lower \
       maintenance costs.".split(" ")[4:10]

['language', 'that', 'lets', 'you', 'work', 'more']
```

Comment: I think...might need to use [5:11] for display in range 5 to 10, right?

Comment: This won't work nicely if there are more than two spaces between words, for that case it's better to use `split()` without parameters, as in my answer.

Comment: You should use [4:10] if you want the fifth and the tenth word

Comment: From 5 to 10. So it should be [5:11]

Answer (score -4):

This is basic stuff, you would do:

```
print "my words are right here haha lol"[5:11]
```

You should most likely take a look at: http://effbot.org/zone/python-list.htm as python strings are similar to list's, and many list functions can be performed on them, such as indexing, which is what your question asks about.

Comment: Wouldn't this show up as a string and do character indexing?  And show the characters 5 to 11. The output would be `rds ar`. That's not word indexing.